# Pig: add all chararrays in a relation to a single tuple

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a text file that contains a list of tags. In the file, each tag is stored on its own line. There are a variable number of tags.

When I load the text file, I do:

```
tags_file = LOAD $list_of_tags AS (tag:chararray);
```

I want to take all the tags in the file and place them in a single tuple that I will pass to a UDF. The UDF will take in two arguments: (1) a bag containing log information and (2) the tuple of tags. In the UDF, I will output a tuple containing the number of times each of the tags appears in the bag containing log information.

I thought of using something like [`ToTuple`](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#totuple) to generate a tuple of the tags but that doesn't work.

How can I add all the `chararray`s in `tags_file` relation into a single tuple that I can pass to a UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use GROUP ALL, FLATTEN and built in function called BagToTuple.

See the code below.

```
A = GROUP tags_file ALL;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(BagToTuple(tags_file));
```

Now B will have tag in a single tuple.